# Table with cell width and height in percentage

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I need this for a simple one-time project and would like to avoid an extended studying of all these newer methods ...

- Am I using CSS correctly in the following code?
- My attempt to have different cell widths in the second row is not working. How this must be done to work?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <style>
        table {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        tr.row1 {
            height: 40%;
        }

        tr.row2 {
            height: 5%;
        }

        tr.row3 {
            height: 55%;
        }

        td.colS {
            width: 40%;
        }

        td.colW {
            width: 60%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row1">
                <td class="colS" style="background-color:red">1</td>
                <td class="colW" style="background-color:green">2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row2">
                <td class="colW" style="background-color:green">3</td>
                <td class="colS" style="background-color:red">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row3">
                <td class="colS" style="background-color:red">5</td>
                <td class="colW" style="background-color:green">6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

> table-layout: fixed

to CSS in to

```
table   {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

like this:

```
table   {height: 100%; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;}
```

```css
   table   {height: 100%; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;}
   tr.row1 {height: 40%}
   tr.row2 {height:  5%}
   tr.row3 {height: 55%}
   td.colS {width:  40%}
   td.colW {width:  60%}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="row1">
<td class="colS" style="background-color:red"  >1</td>
<td class="colW" style="background-color:green">2</td>
</tr>

<tr class="row2">
<td class="colW" style="background-color:green">3</td>
<td class="colS" style="background-color:red"  >4</td>
</tr>

<tr class="row3">
<td class="colS" style="background-color:red"  >5</td>
<td class="colW" style="background-color:green">6</td>
</tr>
  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose a width for the column not individual cells - tables don't work that way.  For instance if you wanted the second column to have a width you could use the following code

```
    <html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">

<style>
   table   {height: 100%;width: 100%}
   tr td:nth-child(2) {width:  80%; }
</style>
</head>

<body>


<table>
<tbody>

<tr class="row1">
<td class="colS" style="background-color:red"  >1</td>

<td class="colW" style="background-color:green">2</td>

</tr>

<tr class="row2">
<td class="colW" style="background-color:green">3</td>

<td class="colS" style="background-color:red"  >4</td>

</tr>

<tr class="row3">
<td class="colS" style="background-color:red"  >5</td>

<td class="colW" style="background-color:green">6</td>

</tr>


</tbody>
</table>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! So there is no way to have different cell widths in different rows? I have to use a separate table for each row?

Comment: In your code the style for tables is defined in the head section, which effects all tables. How to define different styles for more than one table in the head section?